# Tenant specifc files not retrieved in Hyn/multi-tenant Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, storage, multi-tenant

I am unable to display images stored in tenant specific folder but I can upload images to the same tenant folder. The configurations are as follows:

Laravel 5.8

Hyn/multi-tenant 5.3

```
config/filesystems.php

    'tenancy' => [
       'driver' => 'local',
       'root' => storage_path('app/tenancy'),
       'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
       'visibility' => 'public',
      ],

 config/tenancy.php

     'disk' => null,


 Directory structure

 storage
    app
      public
      tenancy
          tenants
            7239b4a43a784604813(tenantfolder)
             user_folder
                     abcd.jpg

 html

 <img height="175" width="175" src="{{ URL::asset    
 ('storage/tenancy/tenants/'.$tenantFolder.$user_folder.'/'.$photo_file_name) }}" />
```

I have tried almost all possible combinations but no result.
I have also created a symlink but it points to app/public directory which I can display image.
Since Hyn/multi-tenancy creates a tenant specific folder, I want to use that and store tenant specific info inside organized folders.

A variety of html tag variations (all I know) were tried but no result.

What is the correct configuration to show images stored in tenant specific folder described above.

Many forums have been surveyed but no clear configurations are spelled.

I have also tried 'media/' instead of 'user_folder' described above and it did work.

Comment: sorry, the '/media/' folder inside the tenant also did not work. it was a typo not was missed.

Comment: Thanks finally, the fallback controller is working and I got it work. May be we need to add a pinch more details in the documentation. Thanks to all